# Message box pops up evertime

Tags: c#

I want the messagebox to only show if the number is equal to 0. That part works the part that is giving me a bit of an issue is, when nudTwoByTwo_1_ValueChanged is at zero and I increment nudTwoByTwo_2_ValueChanged to 1 it still gives me the messagebox everytime I increment nudTwoByTwo_2_ValueChanged. It does that until I increment nudTwoByTwo_1_ValueChanged to 1. I would like for them to work seperatly. If nudTwoByTwo_1_ValueChanged  is set to 0 then throw the messagebox and the same goes for nudTwoByTwo_2_ValueChanged

I am creating a lottery game. the min and max value is set 0-20. I dont want to default the min to 1.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LotteryTickets
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void nudPickFive_1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void nudTwoByTwo_1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbTwoBytwo.Checked)

            errorcheck();

    }

    private void nudTwoByTwo_2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbTwoBytwo.Checked)
        errorcheck();  
    }
    public void errorcheck()
    {



            if (nudTwoByTwo_1.Value == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a number between 1 -20");
            }

    }



    private void gbTwoByTwo_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cbTwoBytwo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Removing the empty methods, better names for the controls + showing us a picture of the GUI might help me understand the problem better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass values to error check.

```
public void errorcheck(int val)
{

        if (val == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number between 1 -20");
        }

}

private void nudTwoByTwo_1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbTwoBytwo.Checked)
        errorcheck((int)nudTwoByTwo_1.Value);
}

private void nudTwoByTwo_2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbTwoBytwo.Checked)
        errorcheck((int)nudTwoByTwo_2.Value);  
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Untested.